# Test and Control analysis to measure the impact of Change in sales-rep for territories

Tags: r, data-analysis, experiments

I hope you all are doing well.

Before I proceed with my problem statement, a few terminologies for reference -

- Territory = Sales Territory - Think of it like a county/region
  assigned to a particular rep and no overlap of area/customers between
  2 Reps
- Rep/ Sales Rep = Sales Representative who visits customers to convert
  sales
- Calls = Number of times a customer is visited by the rep in a month
- Goal Attainment = % of Target achieved for the month - e.g. if Target
  was 500 units and total sales were 600, Attainment is 120%

I am working on a statistical/data-science problem and would like to get some thoughts on how to approach the hypothesis testing.

We have some attributes at Territory level, viz. - `Total Sales`, `New to Brand Sales`, `Total Calls (by Reps)` and `% Goal Attainment`, all rolled-up at Territory-Month level. I have data for 2-years, Jan 2018 to Jan 2020.

Now the problem I want to solve is to do a test & control analyses to see if the ***Sales Rep change*** has any impact on the territory performance (sales) or not. The Test group would be a set of 30 Territories who have **undergone a Rep change** in the last 2 years (Rep changed at least 6 months ago, i.e. no later than July 2019) and the control group having similar territories without any change in Sales Rep for last 2 years.

I want to get some thoughts on how to find a matching control pair for each test territory. I have a list of 107 Territories with 30 having a rep change (basically test group) and remaining 77 available to form a control group. Since `Sales` are my target variable, I'm thinking of creating a composite score on normalized `Calls` and `Goal Attainment` and calculate distance from Mean (or Mean-Squared value) and pair the test territories with control ones having the least distance from mean for the pair.

After my test and control group is formed, I want to conduct hypothesis testing, the null hypothesis being **Rep Change doesn't impact sales** - for this, I'm planning to use ***two-tailed t-test (for n<= 30)*** at 95% significance level. I would really appreciate your thoughts on this approach and If I could do anything else for robust testing.